# Advice on methods to capture lecture board and add notes

Tags: soft-question, advice, learning

I am looking for a method to save the lecture materials, and examples without hand copying from the boards during the lectures. Unfortunately some courses don't have the material available, and sometimes you want to copy a specific example.

EDIT: The reason I would like to avoid copying by hand is that it is sometimes very distracting, especially when the example is complex. I would like to focus on the material itself and devote less time and effort to handwriting it.

So far I thought of using a tablet with an application such as Camscanner to take photos of the board during the lectures. However sometimes I would want to add a hand note or an notation on the photo itself using a stylus pen (or similar).

UPDATE: Camscanner will auto recognize the board boundaries for you and fix the perspective. Also once you took one photo you automatically add subsequent photos to the same document, i.e. same lecture. Very handful feature is that you can add hand notes on the image right after taking it, making notations easy.

Any advice on an effective method or an application designed for that?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to avoid copying by hand? This could be helpful for the answers.

Comment: I would like to point out that copying by hand offers some advantages over taking pictures/filming etc. Do not underestimate that copying stuff by hand (which is bothersome) allows you to better remember the material discussed in a lecture. Therefore, if you lack the time to go over your lecture later that day at home you are better prepared for the next ones coming up. That having said, one of the best ways is to seek an open minded buddy who is willing to share his or her notes.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thank you, I just added it.

Comment: @Marc: I agree with you 100%. Trouble is most of the times the lectures and practices are so fast that it's either listen or copy. Very few manage both.

Comment: I totally agree with you and have struggled with this problem a lot. My experiences concerning copying by hand are above. The advantages of reading along instead of taking notes is that you have more direct time to think about what's happening. I, however, experienced that it's also easier to doze of if you don't take notes, and that quite technical results (eq delta-epsilon proofs) tend to stick less good compared to taking notes. Anyway, try it for yourself, just make sure to intervene in time if you experience the same stuf as me;) Seriously, friendly buddy, if available, works the best.